# Joint filtration vs join of filtrations for counting processes

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

Let $X,Y$ be counting processes without common jumps, i.e. $\Delta X \Delta Y = 0$ $P$-a.s. Denote by $\mathcal{F}_t^X$ and $\mathcal{F}^Y_t$ the filtrations generated by $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Is it true that
$\sigma(X_s,Y_s:s\leq t)=\mathcal{F}_t^X \vee \mathcal{F}_t^Y$? I.e. is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the two processes jointly up to $t$ equal to the join of the two $\sigma$-algebras generated by the respective processes up to $t$?

Comment: The "join" of two $\sigma$-algebras that you denote by $\vee$ cannot be their union in the sense of two sets. It is by all means the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains the two. Then it is trivially equal to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ and $Y$ without further requirements on those processes.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! I think I understand. To sketch the argument, denote $\mathcal G = \sigma(X_s, Y_s : s \leq t)$. By definition of a generated $\sigma$-algebra we have $\mathcal G = \sigma\big( \cup_{s \leq t} \sigma(X_s) \cup \sigma(Y_s) \big)$. Meanwhile, the join $\sigma$-algebra at $t$ is defined as $\mathcal F_t^X \vee \mathcal F_t^Y = \sigma( \mathcal F_t^X \cup \mathcal F_t^Y )$. The inclusion $\mathcal G \subseteq \mathcal F_t^X \vee \mathcal F_t^Y$ is then immediate from these definitions since the generator of the latter is a superset of the generator of the former...

Comment: For the other direction one can e.g. use that $G = \{ A \cap B : A \in \mathcal F_t^X, B \in \mathcal F_t^Y \}$ is a generator of $\mathcal F_t^X \vee \mathcal F_t^Y$. It is easy to see that this generator is also a subset of $\mathcal G$, and therefore $\mathcal F_t^X \vee \mathcal F_t^Y = \sigma(G) \subset \sigma( \mathcal G) = \mathcal G$ by properties of $\sigma$-algebras. I.e. without any special requirements on $X$ and $Y$.